# How do I redirect/save the console to a file and keep it visible on the screen?

Tags: command-line-interface, redirect, console, batch

I want to save a program's output (stdout) to a file but still be able to see the output on the screen in realtime.

I need a solutions for both Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Linux, you can use the `tee` utility.

In Windows, PowerShell contains a `tee` [cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177014.aspx). For `cmd`, you will need to download and install a [separate](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) [utility](http://www.chipstips.com/?p=129).

Answer (score 1):

On Linux and similar systems:

```
program | tee filename
```

The `tee` program sends anything that comes into its standard input to its standard output (like `cat`) and also writes it to the specified file.

Another way to get the same effect would be

```
program >filename 2>/dev/null &
tail -f filename
```

This runs the program in the background, redirecting its standard output to the file, then `tail -f` lets you follow data being written to the file in real time (or nearly so, maybe a fraction of a second delay). The `2>/dev/null` makes the standard error stream disappear so that it doesn't interfere with the output of `tail -f`.

Answer (score 1):

Linux: `command | tee logfile`

Windows: Install cygwin, then run: `command | tee logfile`

Answer (score 0):

For Windows you can do this:

> dir > directory.txt & type directory.txt

where you'd replace `dir` by your application.

If the output scrolls too fast use:

> dir > c:\directory.txt & type c:\directory.txt | more

However, I don't think this would display the contents of the file in real time. You'd have to wait until the process had finished.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you can use `tee` if you download the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) version of it. It's the same as the linux app and comes from the [coreutils package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm).

One word of caution, though: `tee` has its own return code, so you won't be able to notice errors from the process piped to it ([unless you're in linux, then there are ways around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985876/tee-and-exit-status)).